# Is there a Wildcard '%' equivalent in Python as there is in SQL?

Tags: python, regex

I have my code running through a log file that is constantly being updated. I want to pick out the unnecessary lines and have the code worry about 3 lines only. The only problem is those 3 lines begin with a timestamp that is always changing. Here is an example of one of the lines:

`2020-05-19 07:25:46.768:Verbose: InvegoRFIDReaderProcessor:5:CheckSource:Truck Tag=, Reader Connected=True, Reader Address=XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX, Last Msg Time=5/18/2020 11:51:03 AM, ReaderType=Source`

I want to ignore both the timestamp ( *2020-05-19 07:25:46.768:* ) and the end of the line ( *, Last Msg Time=5/18/2020 11:51:03 AM, ReaderType=Source* ) and only worry about the middle of the line. Is there a way i can set a variable equal to the middle of the line only, using something similar to '%' from SQL?

Comment: You can try using python regex

Comment: `%` is to LIKE, as `.*` is to a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading each line as a string, try this:

```py
value = row[row.index("Tag"):row.index(", Last")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to get what you want.

```
import re

text = '2020-05-19 07:25:46.768:Verbose: InvegoRFIDReaderProcessor:5:CheckSource:Truck Tag=, Reader Connected=True, Reader Address=XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX, Last Msg Time=5/18/2020 11:51:03 AM, ReaderType=Source'
result = re.match(r'[\d\-\W:]+(.+),\WL', text)
print(result.group(1))
```

more information about re you can get from here https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

If the whole log is in the variable named **text** you can use  the following code:

```
import re

#assume complete log file is in the text variable
#add code to load log-file into variable "text" HERE

#added sample text
text = """2020-05-19 07:25:46.768:Verbose: InvegoRFIDReaderProcessor:5:CheckSource:Truck Tag=, Reader Connected=True, Reader Address=XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX, Last Msg Time=5/18/2020 11:51:03 AM, ReaderType=Source"""

pattern = re.compile(r'\.\d{3}:([\w:\s=,\.]*)Last')
result = pattern.findall(text)

print(result)
```

This **will match** everything

**after** a **timestamp** like "2020-05-19 07:25:46.768:"

**followed** by "Last Msg Time=5/18/2020 11:51:03 AM, ReaderType=Source"

and put the results in a list named **result**.

I have tested the code with the sample log that you have provided.

You can test any regex here:
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```py
import re

text = '2020-05-19 07:25:46.768:Verbose: InvegoRFIDReaderProcessor:5:CheckSource:Truck Tag=, Reader Connected=True, Reader Address=XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX, Last Msg Time=5/18/2020 11:51:03 AM, ReaderType=Source'

print(re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}(.+)\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/\d{4}', text).group(1))
```